# What is the name of the game where you bid for a hand in decreasing numbers?

Tags: identify-this-game

I play a game where the game play is much like hearts/spades/etc. Standard 52-card deck. Players play one card each "trick" and the highest card gets the trick. (Highest based on lead suit vs trump)

In this variant each player starts with 7 cards, and before the round begins, players must bid on the exact number of tricks the expect to take.

The next round you start with 6 cards, etc. down to 1 card.

I have played this game for a while and would like to look up the official scoring/rules, but cant remember the name of it.
Anyone know the name of this game?

Comment: This sounds very similar to "Wizard", in which you bid on the exact number of trickts you expect to take, but you start at 1 card hands and work your way up to dealing out the entire deck

Comment: What you describe, is a game that I've always called spades, except it was played with an arbitrary number of people (10 people got a bit silly).  Number of cards / hand went from Max Possible, down to 1, then up to max possible.  Which is very different from how Wikipedia describes spades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that game, it goes by many names but is often called "Oh Hell!"

Here's a link for you: http://www.pagat.com/exact/ohhell.html

Comment: Note that this is also called "Up and Down the River."

Comment: Quote from the link:
Its original name Oh Hell! evidently offended some people and has been bowdlerised in many books to Oh Pshaw! or Oh Well!, while others have preferred more robust alternatives such as Oh Shit! Some call it Blob or Blackout... has given rise to the names Elevator (l'Ascenseur in France), Up and Down the River (in Australia and New Zealand) and 10 op en neer in the Netherlands. In Britain it is often known as Nomination Whist... Other names include Bust (in Australia and New Zealand), Boerenbridge (in the Netherlands), Kachuful (in India) and German Bridge (in Hong Kong).

Answer (score 1):

When being polite, we call it "Prediction". We go from maximum cards down to one, then back up to the maximum. We do "simultaneous bidding" as explained at [Pagat](http://www.pagat.com/exact/ohhell.html). However if the total is the same as the number of cards dealt, then the dealer *must* change their bid by one.

Comment: Same here... The idea being that at least a player must be wrong...